# Standalone flash player for Windows CE

Tags: mobile, windows-ce, flash, flashlite

Are there solutions to get de flash player ( doesn't matter what version ( higher = better :) )) running on windows CE in standalone mode ( so not activeX plugin for IE )

or flash lite perhaps ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can contact [BSQUARE](http://www.bsquare.com/flash-ui-extender.aspx). They have a solution for a standalone flash player based on flash-lite 3.1. I couldn't find anything freeware though.
I saw their solution work on an evaluation board by TI (OMAP arm).